# How to get TextView text from a custom Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have a Spinner that is filled with an ArrayAdapter, the ViewHolder in this array Adapter has
two TextView, those are: textViewName, textViewId ( the id textView is hidden ), how can I acess this textView to get their text? I have no ideia, everything is ok, but I don't know how to acess those textView to get their text. I want to get this text after a button has been pressed. Any material I would appreciate, thank you.

Comment: Can you post some sample code what you have tried??

Comment: post your getview() method in addapter

Comment: Could you specify on what case you want to get the text? When clicking an item in the Spinner? when clicking the textview?

Comment: @gpopoteur is onclicking a button. The person'll select a city from this spinner and I want the id from the textviewId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can get the text from the view parameter which passed in onItemSelected like the code below :

```
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {


            // Get selected row data to show on screen
            String Company    = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();
            String CompanyUrl = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub)).getText().toString();
        }
```

});

Comment: I saw a example like your a minute ago, I understood, but there are any ways to get those infromation from another button click, without the onitemselectedlistener? Or I can't acess this view from another place? Could I get the Id from the Spinner and try to acess the view by the Id from another place?

Comment: in my case i used to save the text of the textview spinner in a member variable each time the onItemSelected called . so I can get the last selected value anywhere in the activity .

Comment: I got it Mohanad, but if I don't select a value? My Spinner could come with the selected value already, so I won select another, that shouln'd work is that case, right?

Comment: That is going to work, I made a test and it works, Thanks Mohanad.